# HTTP Status Code 500 when uploading video to server in android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to upload video to server in php and I get Http Status Code 500 error after progress bar complete tasks , I don't know where is the problem in Android file or in JSON file

Android Code for the part of uploading process:

```
   // Uploading Video  to server
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {



            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server


            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

My JSON file:

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

 // getting server ip address
 $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

 // final file url that is being uploaded
 $file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'testApp' . '/' . $target_path;


 if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);



$response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


try {
    // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        // make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
    }

    // File successfully uploaded
    $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}
 } else {
// File parameter is missing
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
 }

 // Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: that is internal Server Error

Comment: I tried to change the max size of upload and post from server what I can do more ?

Comment: Check your server logs and see if there are any errors logged there. Usually you encounter 500 code when there's an error on the server side when processing a request.

Comment: @Pubudu Call to undefined function  gethostname() , I make comment for this and give me the same error at log error of server

Comment: $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()); <<< Ah so your error occurs at this particular line? If so, that means there is no function called gethostname(). Where is this function supposed to be defined? Check and see if it is there

Comment: @Pubudu I deleted this line and I write server manually but the status code is 404 , I tried to call support of my server but It's saying the problem may be from code because the server is ok !

Comment: @Pubudu I solved it by add something to the request url , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After taking with server support I have this solution to the request of url:

Should be like this:
http://yourIPaddress/~username_that_is_using_to_enter_to_the_controlpanel/YourFolder/filename.php